# getResponseCode - skip the actual wait?

Tags: java

I paid someone for a little java work (I don't know java well) to send data from a java applet to a php script. She used the below code for this - and it works great, but the problem is that it hangs. It's not bad, but this is sending data every 3 seconds in a game that runs at 60 fps so the freeze is very noticeable.

Is there any possible way to salvage this technique and keep the applet running full speed?

```
private String sendHttpRequest(String value, String url) {
    try {

        // Use it for GET request. Rename/Add other parameters if you need.
        URL obj = new URL(url + "?q=" + value);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); // set any user agent that you want

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: `@Async` from spring, or any other technique to asynchronize the request, see also [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/proxies-done-right-with-guavas-abstractinvocationhandler.html)

Answer (score 0):

This a matter of synchronous vs asynchronous design.
Is she doing this in a separate thread in your applet?
If not, she could try doing it in a separate thread.